# Listing Dates In Order (Options Drop-Down)

Tags: php

I want to produce a form that has a dropdown options box containing dates in order and in a format but I have no idea how to display them as a string.

I assume that you need to do this sort of thing to get the start and finish but how can I get the dates for each "Option"?

```
    <?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$start = date('Ymd');
$end = date('Ymd', strtotime('+60 days'));

while (strtotime($start) <= strtotime($end)) {
    echo "$start\n";
    $date = date ("Ymd", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($start)));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dates = array();
$dates[] = time();

for ($i = 1; $i < 60; $i++) { $dates[] = strtotime("+{$i} days"); }


$html = NULL;

foreach ($dates as $date) { $dates .= "<option value='" . date('Ymd', $date) . "'>" . date('d F Y', $date) . "</option>"; }

$html = "<select id='dates'>{$dates}</select>";

echo $html;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just like to add to [Publi Design](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2748327/publi-design)'s answer to make the answer more specific to the question.

PHP courtesy of **Publi Design**:

```
// Start date
$date = '2009-12-06';
// End date
$end_date = '2020-12-31';
?>
<select id="dates">
<?php while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) { ?>
   <option name="date"><?php echo (string)$date; ?></option> 
<?php   $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date))); 
   }?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a basic PHP `while` loop:

```
// Set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

// Start date
$date = '2009-12-06';
// End date
$end_date = '2020-12-31';

while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
    echo "$date\n";
    $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
}
```

Original source: [here](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/php-loop-through-dates-from-date-to-date-with-strtotime-function/)

Comment: Thanks but this is showing a continual loop - I've updated my code

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for..

```
<select id="dates">
<option></option>
<?php
   $curr_date = date('YYMMDD');

   for ($i = 0; $i < 60; $i++) {
       $date = strtotime("+$i day", $curr_date);
       echo '<option name="date" value="'.$date.'">'.date('DD m YY', strtotime($date)).'</option>'."\n";
   }
?>
</select>
```